# Access Denied message when trying to open hidden folder in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

[image]

Earlier i was using one [batch file](http://errorcode401.blogspot.in/2013/06/FFlocker-1.0.html) to lock my file/folder in windows. That time i locked my one folder from D Drive. It was working fine for me. But after some windows update i am not able to unlock my folder using this batch file.

I know this batch file is using cacls command to change the attribute of folder. It changes it's attribute as hidden and system folder. I tried cacls command as well from cmd but still it gives me Access Denied error.

Please suggest me any approach to get access to this folder. It will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please review [MCVE]. Hard to advise with so little information. The fflocker image is pretty, but why is it there?

Comment: cacls.exe and icacls.exe modify the file security descriptor (i.e. the owner, mandatory integrity level, and list of discretionary access control entries). File attributes, such as hidden and system, are modified via attrib.exe.

Comment: @jwdonahue i will take a look.